# Equal elements and Tree set

Tags: java, treeset

Created a static nested class  which implements `Comparable`, and override Object.equals such that `e1.compareTo(e2)==0` and `e1.equals(e2)==true` are not synonymous.

Then i add the objects into `TreeSet` and `HashSet` respectively using its add method.

I expected  that insertion of multiple such objects into either a TreeSet or a HashSet will succeed, since both claim reliance on equals to determine uniqueness but i found inserting multiple such objects into a `TreeSet` will fail  while inserting them into a `HashSet` will succeed.

```
public class Test {

    /*
     * This inner class deliberately has a compareTo method that is not
     * consistent with equals
     */
    static class TestObject implements Comparable<TestObject> {
        @Override
        public int compareTo(TestObject arg0) {
            // No two of these objects can be ordered
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
            // No two of these objects are ever equal to each other
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void printSuccess(boolean success) {
        if (success)
            System.out.println(" Success");
        else
            System.out.println(" Failure");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<TestObject> testTreeSet = new TreeSet<TestObject>();
        HashSet<TestObject> testHashSet = new HashSet<TestObject>();

        System.out.println("Adding to the HashSet:");
        printSuccess(testHashSet.add(new TestObject()));
        printSuccess(testHashSet.add(new TestObject()));
        printSuccess(testHashSet.add(new TestObject()));

        System.out.println("Copying to the TreeSet:");
        for (TestObject to : testHashSet) {
            printSuccess(testTreeSet.add(to));
        }
    }
}
```

Output of above program is

```
Adding to the HashSet:
 Success
 Success
 Success
Copying to the TreeSet:
 Success
 Failure
 Failure
```

Can some one tell me why Tree set is behaving like this ?

Comment: Perhaps their `hashCode` is the same?

Comment: @Shark--Hash set is adding all the objects

Comment: [a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

Comment: I can't even [get your code to compile](http://rextester.com/PBX38682) in a demo.  It complains that `hashCode()` was never overriden.  Perhaps the same hash code is being used for all instances.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS --API documentation for TreeSet.add(E e) is

"Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2))."

Comment: Maybe because you try to add non-orderable elements to a TreeSet, which needs to order elements.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen--It is compiling fine on my machine .

Comment: This question is obsolete since your `hashcode`/`equals` contract is broken. any two objecs for whom `o1.equals(o2)` is true **must** have the **same hashcode**. This also implies that there are no two objects in a Hash-based collection for whom `o1.equals(o2)` is true.

Comment: @ShowStopper looks like the JavaDoc is inconsistent and they just used the standard description for the add method. If you look at the source of TreeSet you will see that by default it uses a TreeMap to save data and in the TreeMap class put method it only uses the comparator or compareTo methods of the objects to check for equality, but never the equals method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal". https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html
And your compareTo says they are all equal.

Answer (score 6):

The return value 0 for `compareTo` means the objects are equal, so `e1.compareTo(e2) == 0` if and only if `e1.equals(e2) == true`.

TreeSet guarantees oredering so it uses the compare method, and HashSet does not so it uses the equals method. Try changing the compareTo method to a positive/negative number instead.

You can read more about the Compareable interface [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Comment: API documentation for TreeSet.add(E e) is "Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2))."

Comment: From the TreeSet doc: "TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal". Because they trust the programmer to keep the contract of Compareable, equals is the same as compareTo resulting 0.

Answer (score 0):

Also the [javadoc of `java.util.Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) explicitly describes this case and tells that `Comparator` for `SortedSet` must be consistent with `equals`:

> For example, suppose one adds two elements a and b such that
>   (a.equals(b) && c.compare(a, b) != 0) to an empty TreeSet with
>   comparator c. The second add operation will return true (and the size
>   of the tree set will increase) because a and b are not equivalent from
>   the tree set's perspective, even though this is contrary to the
>   specification of the Set.add method.